# How to retrieve my security group id in terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Please help me out I am new in Terraform. I have created two security group by terrform module. Now I wanted to allow first sg1 into sg2 and sg2 into sg1.

For this I need both security group id in module. can you please help me for same.

**Module main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
  access_key = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
  secret_key = "${var.awssecretkey}"
}

module "sg1" {
  source              = "./sg_create"
  sg_name             = "sg1"
  vpcname             = "${var.vpcnames}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  awssecretkey        = "${var.awssecretkey}"
  awsaccesskey        = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
}

module "sg2" {
  source              = "./sg_create"
  sg_name             = "sg2"
  vpcname             = "${var.vpcnames}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  awssecretkey        = "${var.awssecretkey}"
  awsaccesskey        = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
}

output "sgid" {
  value = ${sg2.aws_security_group.sg_create.id}
}
```

**module variable.tf**

```
variable "region" {
  type = string
  default = "ap-southeast-1"
}

variable "awsaccesskey" {
  type = string
  default = "***********************"
}

variable "awssecretkey" {
  type = string
  default = "**********************************************"
}

variable "vpcnames" {
  type = string
  default = "firstvpc"
}
```

**sg_create/main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
  access_key = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
  secret_key = "${var.awssecretkey}"
}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.vpcname}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg_create" {
  name        = "${var.sg_name}"
  description = "${var.sg_name}"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}"
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.sg_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_all" {
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = 0
  to_port = 0
  protocol = "-1"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg_create.id}"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg_create.id}"
}
```

**sg_create/variable.tf**

```
variable "region" {
  type = string
}

variable "awsaccesskey" {
  type = string
}

variable "awssecretkey" {
  type = string
}

variable "sg_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "vpcname" {
  type = string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

**sg_create/main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
  access_key = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
  secret_key = "${var.awssecretkey}"
}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.vpcname}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg_create" {
  name        = "${var.sg_name}"
  description = "${var.sg_name}"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}"
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.sg_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_all" {
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = 0
  to_port = 0
  protocol = "-1"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg_create.id}"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg_create.id}"
}

output "sg_id" {
  value = "${aws_security_group.sg_create.id}"
}
```

**Module main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
  access_key = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
  secret_key = "${var.awssecretkey}"
}

module "sg1" {
  source              = "./sg_create"
  sg_name             = "sg1"
  vpcname             = "${var.vpcnames}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  awssecretkey        = "${var.awssecretkey}"
  awsaccesskey        = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
}

module "sg2" {
  source              = "./sg_create"
  sg_name             = "sg2"
  vpcname             = "${var.vpcnames}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  awssecretkey        = "${var.awssecretkey}"
  awsaccesskey        = "${var.awsaccesskey}"
}

output "this_security_group_id" {
  value = "${module.sg2.sg_id}"
}
```